# using panda3d without graphic stuff in c++?

Tags: c++, panda3d

I'm trying to write a windowless panda3d program, as a dedicated server.
And I don't know how to use panda3d without creating any graphic stuff.

I have tried this:

```
load_prc_file_data("", "window-type none"); // do not effect.
load_prc_file_data("", "window-type offscreen"); // cause errors while running PandaFramework::open_window();
```

Actually I posted this on [Panda3d Forums](https://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18941)
And the only one answered told me not to do `PandaFramework::open_window()`;
But in `panda3d-cpp` I don't know how to work without a `WindowFramework`, to be honest, I don't even know if the program works correctly.

Currently using:
Panda3d1.9.2
Qt5.7.0
MSVC2015
Windows10SDK

Full core of .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/python/include"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/python/libs/python27.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libp3framework.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libpanda.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libpandafx.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libpandaexpress.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libp3dtool.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libp3dtoolconfig.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libp3pystub.lib"
LIBS += "G:/Panda3D-1.9.2/lib/libp3direct.lib"
```

Full core of .cpp file:

```
#include <pandaFramework.h>
#include <pandaSystem.h>
#include <load_prc_file.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PandaFramework pFramework;
    pFramework.open_framework(argc, argv);
    load_prc_file_data("", "window-type offscreen"); // cause errors
    WindowFramework *pWindow = pFramework.open_window();
    pFramework.main_loop();
    pFramework.close_framework();
    return 0;
}
```

Could somebody help me about this?

Comment: It would help if you would write down some of the your code you wish to run in the example. do you want it event driven?
do you want it to be simple and do some calculations when possible?

Comment: Instead of a WindowFramework, Shouldn't you use a GraphicsBuffer?

Comment: @Jonathan, I'm just a Panda3d begineer and want to know if I can use Panda3D in client/server architecture games.

Comment: @wasthishelpful, Could you give me some examples about this?

Comment: Still no one can answer this question? :(

Comment: Oops?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple: if you don't want to open a window, don't call `open_window`.  You'll still have access to the `AsyncTaskManager::get_global_ptr()` for scheduling tasks, to `Loader` for loading models, and you can create a scene graph by just creating a `NodePath(new PandaNode("root"))` and attaching objects to it, etc.

The `window-type` .prc variable has no effect in `PandaFramework`, since creating a window is an explicit operation there.